# Power of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be defined as:
>   $$T\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} 5\,y+13\,x \\ -12\,y-30\,x \end{array}\right)$$
>
> Find: $T^{4}\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)$

I have found the diagonal $[T]_B=\begin{pmatrix}
    3       & 0  \\
      0       &-2 
\end{pmatrix}$ where $B$ is the canonical basis.

So what is left to do is  $T^{4}\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}
    3       & 0  \\
      0       &-2 
\end{pmatrix}^4\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3^4 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: You've got the wrong matrix for $T$.

Comment: Are you sure that $T^4$ is the **power** of $T$, rather than the $4$-fold composition of $T$? In other words: I would interpret $T^4(x)$ as $T(T(T(T(x))))$.

Comment: Recognizing the nature of the question, I would read it as $T*T*T*T$ meaning $T$ to the fourth power$. But I could be wrong... However, Augustin certainly got a point there to be considered.

Comment: clearly I have skipped some important steps, the written $[T]_B$ is the diagonal matrix

Comment: But the *power interpretation* would not make sense as long as you have not defined what the power of a vector means. If $T\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} c \\ d \end{pmatrix}$ then how to compute $\begin{pmatrix} c \\ d \end{pmatrix}^4$? I really think that the 4-fold composition is meant and not the 4th power.

Comment: I was told to use the following fact :$\left[T^n \right ]_B=\left[T \right ]_B^n$

Comment: If the power is written on the vector, certainly agreed. If the power is on the matrix, like it is in case of for example stochastic processes, then it is repetitive multiplication of the matrix...